# In Scala, how to use `Nothing` as returned value to Fake a method?

Tags: scala, testing, functional-programming, mocking, type-inference

I'd like to create a method called `save` and haven't been ready to implement it. However, I don't want it to throw exceptions during evaluated. So I tried to make it return a `Nothing` as the result.

```
def save[A <: AuthInfo](profile: CommonSocialProfile): Future[UserProfile] = {
  // To be done
  new Nothing()
}
```

But this won't work, the compiler says:

> class Nothing is abstract; cannot be instantiated

I also tried `???` as a placeholder, but that will throw a `NotImplementedError`, which doesn't fit my needs either..

```
def save[A <: AuthInfo](profile: CommonSocialProfile): Future[UserProfile] = ???
```

Does anyone have easier ways about fake a method in Scala?

Comment: If it's really fake and you will provide the actual implementation later maybe you can just return `null` :)

Comment: There can never be an instance of `Nothing`, because `Nothing` is... well, nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to return something of type `Future[UserProfile]`, you'll just need to make up a fake `UserProfile` and return it.

So if `UserProfile` is defined like this:

```
class UserProfile(id: Int, name: String)
```

then do something like:

```
def save[A <: AuthInfo](profile: CommonSocialProfile): Future[UserProfile] = {
  // To be done
  Future(new UserProfile(-1, ""))
}
```

Or, perhaps you want a special `UserProfile` singleton for this purpose:

```
object FakeUserProfile extends UserProfile(-1, "")

def save[A <: AuthInfo](profile: CommonSocialProfile): Future[UserProfile] = {
  // To be done
  Future(FakeUserProfile)
}
```